# Stress Test POST with Multiple Body using Apache JMeter

Tags: java, post, jmeter, stress-testing

How can I stress test POST multiple Body with specified body data?

Here are my Body Data:

```sh
{
  "car": {
    "brand": "toyota",
    "model": "avanza",
  },
  "customer_id": "string"
}
```

How can I stress test it with multiple body from that ?

example like this one:

```sh
{
  "car": {
    "brand": "toyota",
    "model": "avanza",
  },
  "customer_id": "string"
}

{
  "car": {
    "brand": "daihatsu",
    "model": "xenia",
  },
  "customer_id": "string"
}

{
  "car": {
    "brand": "suzuki",
    "model": "ertiga",
  },
  "customer_id": "string"
}
```

I have tried using `User Defined Variables`, but I can't use this one because I need specific body data from `brand` and `model`. Not like this `brand = toyota, model = ertiga`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you need to store these brand/model pairs somewhere, i.e. in a file which looks like:

   ```
   toyota,avanza
   suzuki,ertiga
   daihatsu,xenia
   ```
2. Second, you need to **generate** the request body JSON (by the way, your example [is not valid](https://jsonlint.com/), my code snippet assumes the following output:

   ```
   [
     {
       "car": {
         "brand": "toyota",
         "model": "avanza"
       },
       "customer_id": "string"
     },
     {
       "car": {
         "brand": "daihatsu",
         "model": "xenia"
       },
       "customer_id": "string"
     },
     {
       "car": {
         "brand": "suzuki",
         "model": "ertiga"
       },
       "customer_id": "string"
     }
   ]
   ```

   Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor,) as a child of the request you want to parameterize and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def payload = []

   new File('test.csv').readLines().each { line ->
       def car = [:]
       car.put('brand', line.split(',')[0])
       car.put('model', line.split(',')[1])
       def car_entry = [:]
       car_entry.put('car', car)
       car_entry.put('customer_id', 'string')
       payload.add(car_entry)
   }

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the generated request body as `${payload}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 1):

You can parametrize band/model and try to read in form csv file
so your body will be as below

```
"car": {
    "brand": "${BRAND}",
    "model": "${MODEL}"},
"customer_id": "string"}
```

Your csv file will be as below

```
BRAND,MODEL
toyota,avanza
suzuki,ertiga
daihatsu,xenia
```

to read data from CSV check out [CSV_Data_Set_Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)